# After reloading div content via AJAX, updated html disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have JS code which reloads my div every 2 seconds:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
    $('#indexRefresh').load('/includes/index_refresh_include.php?_=' + Math.random());
}, 2000);
```

Then I make an AJAX request which loads more content when a 'load more' button is pressed, but since it's reloading the loaded content disappears.

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".loadmore", function() {
        var ID = $(this).attr("id");
        var split = ID.split("-");
        if (ID) {
            $("#more" + ID).html('<img src="moreajax.gif" />');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "loadmore.php",
                data: "rowstart=" + ID,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("#updates").append(html);
                    $("#more" + ID).remove();
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            $(".morebox").html('The End');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

What should I do so the loaded content won't disappear?

EDIT:

this is the html

```
echo"<div id='indexRefresh'>";
        include INC.'index_include.php';
echo"</div>";
```

this is the index_refresh_include.php file

```
$result1 = dbquery("SELECT DISTINCT model_id, model_username FROM models LEFT JOIN `show` ON models.model_id=show.show_model_id ORDER BY show_ended=0 DESC, model_id ASC LIMIT 6");

$rowstart = 0;
echo"<section class='list'>";
echo"    <div id='updates'>";
echo"        <div class='small_block'>";
while($data = dbarray($result1)){
    $modelID = $data['model_id'];
    $result = dbquery("SELECT * FROM `show` WHERE show_model_id='$modelID'");
    if(dbrows($result) >= 5){
        echo"    <article>";
    } else {
        echo"    <article class='new'>";
    }
    echo"           <a class='checkcam' href='checkcam.php?model=".$data['model_username']."'>";
    echo"               <img src='".getAvatar($data['model_id'])."' alt='' />";
    echo"           </a>";
    echo"       </article>";
    $rowstart++;
}
echo"        </div>";

$blockstart = 0;
$large = dbquery("SELECT * FROM largeblocks WHERE large_status=1 ORDER BY large_pos ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET $blockstart");
if(dbrows($large) != 0){
    while($block = dbarray($large)){
        echo"        <div class='large_block'>";
        echo"            <article>";
        echo"                <a href='Cam.php?show=1'>";
        echo"                    <img src='http://placehold.it/600x600' alt='' />";
        echo"                </a>";
        echo"            </article>";
        echo"        </div>";
        $blockstart++;
    }
} else {
    $model = dbquery("SELECT * FROM models ORDER BY model_credits DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET $blockstart");
    while($block = dbarray($model)){
        echo"        <div class='large_block'>";
        echo"            <article>";
        echo"               <a class='checkcam' href='checkcam.php?model=".$block['model_username']."'>";
        echo"                   <img src='".getAvatar($block['model_id'], '600x600')."' alt='' />";
        echo"                </a>";
        echo"            </article>";
        echo"        </div>";
        $blockstart++;
    }
}

echo"        <br class='clear' />";

$large = dbquery("SELECT * FROM largeblocks WHERE large_status=1 ORDER BY large_pos ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET $blockstart");
if(dbrows($large) != 0){
    while($block = dbarray($large)){
        echo"        <div class='large_block'>";
        echo"            <article>";
        echo"                <a href='Cam.php?show=1'>";
        echo"                    <img src='http://placehold.it/600x600' alt='' />";
        echo"                </a>";
        echo"            </article>";
        echo"        </div>";
        $blockstart++;
    }
} else {
    $model = dbquery("SELECT * FROM models ORDER BY model_credits DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET $blockstart");
    while($block = dbarray($model)){
        echo"        <div class='large_block'>";
        echo"            <article>";
        echo"               <a class='checkcam' href='checkcam.php?model=".$block['model_username']."'>";
        echo"                   <img src='".getAvatar($block['model_id'], '600x600')."' alt='' />";
        echo"                </a>";
        echo"            </article>";
        echo"        </div>";
        $blockstart++;
    }
}

$result1 = dbquery("SELECT DISTINCT model_id, model_username FROM models LEFT JOIN `show` ON models.model_id=show.show_model_id ORDER BY show_ended=0 DESC, model_id ASC LIMIT 6 OFFSET $rowstart");

echo"        <div class='small_block'>";
while($data = dbarray($result1)){
    $modelID = $data['model_id'];
    $result = dbquery("SELECT * FROM `show` WHERE show_model_id='$modelID'");
    if(dbrows($result) >= 5){
        echo"    <article>";
    } else {
        echo"    <article class='new'>";
    }
    echo"               <a class='checkcam' href='checkcam.php?model=".$data['model_username']."'>";
    echo"                   <img src='".getAvatar($data['model_id'])."' alt='' />";
    echo"               </a>";
    echo"           </article>";
    $rowstart++;
}


echo"        </div>";

echo"        <br class='clear' />";

echo"    </div>";

echo"    <div id='more$rowstart-$blockstart' class='morebox'>";
echo"        <a href='#' class='loadmore gardient' id='$rowstart-$blockstart'>".$lang['index_loadmore']."</a>";
echo"    </div>";

echo"</section>";
```

Comment: Is the element in which you load the `more` content nested inside the `indexRefresh` div?

Comment: a `ajax`-request won't reload a page. What element is `.loadmore` ? To clarify your problem you shold add your html-markup

Comment: We need to see the structure of the html page. BTW /includes/index_refresh_include.php?_=' +Math.random() won't guarantee that you bypass the cache every time. You need to set the cache control headers

Comment: yes and it need to reload too, like the first content.. basically there is a php script which gets content from mysql database, and the js script is reloading it, if any of the content's changes their position, and the load more button just loads more of the content from the database

Comment: As a general rule with jQuery questions, please provide the output HTML (e.g. as saved from your browser) so we do not have to mentally interpret PHP :)

Comment: what did you need the reload for? why not just recheck if there's new thing then append that new thing to the start rather than reloading it every 2sec

Comment: i used reload because i thought it would be simplier, because there are blocks who change places, for example, the last block could in any moment become the first block, basically if in mysql database the row gets status 1 it becomes first, if it has status 0, it goes after all the rows with status 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct code

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
    $('<div></div>').appendTo('#indexRefresh').load('/includes/index_refresh_include.php?_=' +Math.random());
}, 2000);
```

This appends each time a < div > on div with id=indexRefresh. And then loads inside the new div the URL

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pgueavwo/)

Comment: Wouldn't this just duplicate the content every 2 seconds?

Comment: @SheldonNeilson You were right. I have fixed it now

Comment: it creates multiple duplicates every 2 seconds

Comment: @SpeekaDievs No, it appends a div on the main div, and then loads inside the last div the URL

Comment: as i saw in fiddle, visually it creates duplicates of the login form

Comment: yes, actually this is for demo purpose. Op passes a param and normally it would display different content each time. with the last content always appended at the bottom

Comment: i didn't quite understand how to make it not to duplicate everything and will this wont remove the appended content?

Comment: @SpeekaDievs see my update. No it will not duplicate everything. Like the fiddle, one div is added at the end of `indexRefresh` and then the contents of the URL are loaded inside the added div.